# Jquery Remove loop animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am looping to items but when it loop back to the first div, an animation is happening, i only need a switching div without animation on interval

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function telephone() {
        $("#div1").delay(3000).hide(0, function () {
            $("#div2").show();
        });
        $("#div2").delay(6000).hide(0, function () {
            $("#div1").show(telephone);
        });
    }
    telephone();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7NXz/542/

Comment: What is your desired result ? what you expect from your code to do ?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/yy176ve0/1/ ?

Comment: yes but it should loop

Comment: A loop to display each div three seconds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yy176ve0/3/)**

If you want to switch between the two divs every 3 seconds, use javascript function **[setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)** and jquery function **[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** :

```js
setInterval(function(){
    $("#div2, #div1").toggle();
}, 3000);
```

```css
#div2 {
    display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">phone1</div>
<div id="div2">phone2</div>
```

I'm not sure if that really what you want but hope this helps.